# How to recover Windows password from launched Windows EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a Windows EC2 launched from an AMI for which I no longer have the password.
I tried running:

```
aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id i-instanceId
```

and also:

```
aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id i-instanceId --priv-launch-key C:\key.pem
```

But the output is this:

```
{
    "InstanceId": "i-instanceId",
    "Timestamp": "2017-11-03T18:05:35.000Z",
    "PasswordData": ""
}
```

Trying to get the password by doing this well after 1h of launching the instance:

[image]

Returns this:

[image]

Is there any way of recovering the password?

Comment: Was the AMI this instance was sourced from configured to enable retrieving the password from the console?

Comment: Probably not :( I don't remember configuring anything in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

Recovering a Windows password is not too difficult.

Summary of the steps involved:

> 1. Spin up a new Windows instance with the same OS version.
> 2. Detach the disk drive from the Windows instance that you forgot the password.
> 3. Attach the disk drive to the new Windows instance.
> 4. Modify `config.xml` to reset the password.
> 5. Reverse the above steps.

Here is a document that details everything step by step.

Source: [Resetting the Windows Administrator Password Using EC2Config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use AWS Systems Manager and EC2Rescue for both an online and offline password recovery.

Here are the steps:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/reset-admin-password/

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

AWS guidance for this situation:

> To reset an Administrator password for an EC2 instance, modify a
>   configuration file on the instance boot volume. However, you can't
>   modify this file if the volume is attached to the instance as a root
>   volume. You must detach the volume and attach it to a temporary
>   instance. After you modify the configuration file on the temporary
>   instance, you reattach it to your original instance as the root
>   volume.

AWS has provided a step-by-step instructions for this situation in their official documentation that is too long for this answer, and differs somewhat depending on your server version because of changes to their EC2Config/EC2Launch configuration utilities over time:

- [Instructions for Windows Server 2016 / EC2Launch Users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Launch.html)

  - Install the [EC2Rescue](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2rescue/windows/EC2Rescue_latest.zip) utility to your temporary instance and select 'Reset Administrator Password' in the 'Detected possible issues' UI.
- [Instructions for Windows Server before 2016 / EC2Config Users](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ResettingAdminPassword_EC2Config.html)

  - On your temporary instance, find `\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings\config.xml` and update the `Ec2SetPassword` plugin value from 'Disabled' to 'Enabled' and save the file.